# New to programming language, need help to read a .dat file into array Vs VB, console .net framework

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to read from a data file called TXT.dat and store the circled values into a separate array's using the type of commands I have used.  I cannot use streamreader,streamwriter  this is what I am learning at university but we were taught to read an array not certain values as I will be tested using a file which has
2 factorial values from a single file and store int two arrays.

I have spent hours trying before going to paid sites who always answer with i/o streamreader which doesnt help

[.dat file i created to practice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VocfG.jpg)

MY CODE

```
Sub Main()
    Const i_val As Integer = 6
    Dim j As Integer = 6 'loop readers

    Dim Arayn_Fact(i_val - 1) As Double 'array for 2nd value per line
    Dim Aray_Fact2n(j - 1) As Double 'array for 4th value per line


    Read_Values(i_val - 1, Arayn_Fact)



End Sub
Sub Read_Values(ByVal i As Integer, ByRef _A() As Double)
    Dim fid1 As Integer = FreeFile()
    Dim fid2 As Integer = FreeFile() + 1
    Dim tmp As Double
    FileOpen(fid1, "TXT.dat", OpenMode.Input, OpenAccess.Read)
    For i = 0 To 5 Step 1
        Input(fid1, tmp)
        Input(fid1, _A(i))
    Next i
    FileClose(fid1)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Comment: If you can't use streamreader, then presumably there is something specific that you are supposed to use?  Unless you're required to use them, I would strongly recommend avoiding `FileOpen` and `Input`, they are for legacy support for pre-.NET VB file handling.

Comment: I don't know why they want you use VB.NET and then force you to use prehistoric methods like FreeFile, FileOpen and Input. However if you want to read only the second column from the data inside the file then you should read all the data in a line (5 inputs) before going to read the input from the next line

Comment: FileOpen(), FileClose(), and FreeFile() aren't a thing. They exist only for backwards compatibility with very old code, and have no place in new development. If this is what your university is teaching, find a new university.

Comment: Yeah, add the final line from @JoelCoehoorn comment to mine as well.

Comment: "My experience with university taught programmers is that it takes them a year or more to unlearn all the bad practices that university taught them; and to grasp the realities of actual programming in the industry." Robert. C. Martin (Uncle Bob)

Answer (score 0):

First, some style things. Passing the array `ByRef` is incorrect. Arrays are already reference types, and so passing `ByVal` still passes the reference to the array object. But don't even pass the array in the first place. It's better practice to let the `Read_Values()` method create and return the array to the calling function.

And ***no one*** uses that ancient/ganky `FileOpen()` API anymore. I mean that. NO. ONE. It's not even appropriate for teaching, as the `Stream` types are closer to what the low level operating system/file system are doing. If you can't use StreamReader and friends, there are still better options out there.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Array_Fact() As Double = Read_Values("TXT.dat", 1)
    Dim Array_Fact2n() As Double  = Read_Values("TXT.dat", 3) 
    Console.ReadKey(True)
End Sub

Function Read_Values(filePath As String, position As Integer) As Double()
    Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(filePath) 'Look Ma, no StreamReader
    Dim result(lines.Length - 1) As Double

    For i As Integer = 0 To Lines.Length - 1
        result(i) = Double.Parse(lines(i).Split(",")(position).Trim())
    Next line

    Return result
End Function
```

But what I'd *really* do is keep the 2nd and 4th values in the *same collection* and read everything in one pass through the file. This uses features like Generics, Tuples, Lambdas+Linq, and more that you won't get to for some time, but I feel like it's useful to show you where you're going:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Facts = Read_Values("TXT.dat")
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",Facts.Select(Function(f) $"({f.Item1}:{f.Item2})")))
    Console.ReadKey(True)
End Sub

Function Read_Values(filePath As String) As IEnumerable(Of (Double, Double))
    Return File.ReadLines(filePath).Select(
        Function(line) 'Poor man's CSV. In real code, I'd pull in a CSV parser from NuGet
            Dim fields = line.Split(",")
            Return (Double.Parse(fields(1).Trim()), Double.Parse(fields(3).Trim()))
        End Function
    )
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too fancy, here's some very basic code to do what you've outlined:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim fileName As String = "txt.dat"

    Dim Aray_Fact2() As Integer 'array for 2nd value per line
    Dim Aray_Fact4() As Integer 'array for 4th value per line

    Dim list2 As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim list4 As New List(Of Integer)

    Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
    For Each line As String In lines
        Dim values() As String = line.Split(",")
        If values.Length >= 3 Then
            Dim f2, f4 As Integer
            If Integer.TryParse(values(1), f2) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(values(3), f4) Then
                list2.Add(f2)
                list4.Add(f4)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid value in line: " & line)
            End If
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid number of entries in line: " & line)
        End If
    Next

    Aray_Fact2 = list2.ToArray
    Aray_Fact4 = list4.ToArray

    Console.WriteLine("Aray_Fact2: " & String.Join(",", Aray_Fact2))
    Console.WriteLine("Aray_Fact4: " & String.Join(",", Aray_Fact4))
    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit...")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

If you are completely against the use of Lists and ToArray, then you'd have to read the file TWICE.  Once to determine how many lines are in the file so you can dimension the arrays to the correct size.  Then another time to actually read the values and populate the arrays.

Comment: The commands I am using are taught in ENGG1002 currently.  I used streamreader my last assignment and was heavily deducted

Comment: Yeah...I have no idea what is allowed in your ENGG1002 course, sorry.  Do you know if `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` is permissible?  I could certainly update this code to use the older, legacy functions.  Will you know the number of lines in your data file beforehand?